# How to connect remotely SQL Database to Cpanel?

Tags: sql-server, cpanel

I am not able to connect my SQL database to Cpanel , I tried different ways but not connecting....so could someone give me the complete step to connect.

Comment: Here is a tutorial... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YbIn--iNmKE

Comment: i did that already....i need the steps connect SQL database to Cpanel

Answer (score 1):

First you will have to enable MSSQL support with your PHP and by default it's not enable so please contact your hosting provider and ask them to enable this for you.

http://forums.cpanel.net/threads/mssql-support.276132/